# Figuring out the efficiency of this method

Tags: java, algorithm, structure

I have come across while developing my program in Java. I need to figure out how efficient this method is in Big-O notation.

This is what my boss told me:

> Making use of a suitable Big-O expression, state and explain in some detail the
> time complexity of method compute.
> Your explanation must include a justification for the chosen Big-O expression and
> make reference to the number of calls to compute at Line 6.

```html
public int compute(int[] array, int first, int last) {
        int result = 0;
        
        if(first < last) {
            result = array[first] + compute(array, first+2, last);
        }
        else if(first < array.length) {
            result = array[first];
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is ```last``` here?

Comment: first and last correspond to valid indexes in the array

Comment: Your "boss" told you that? You know it's not forbidden to post homework questions here, as long as [you follow some guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). I've also taken the liberty to [remove your request for an urgent reply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: Was it your boss, or your teacher, that asked you? :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer problems like this, it's useful to walk through the code yourself and see what it does. Once you can put the method into regular words, it usually becomes much easier to figure out the efficiency.

What does this method do, then? It adds together every other number in the array from `first` to `last`. Examining it closer, we can break the function down into

- The base cases

  - `else if (first < array.length) { ... }` returns the element at index `first`, or the constant `0`. Since array-indexing is a constant-time operation, this branch executes in constant time.
  - Implicitly, `result` remains 0 if neither of the above cases are triggered. This is obviously constant-time.
- The recursive case `if (first < last)`. In this case, we end up returning the `array[first]` added to the recursive result of calling the function with `first+2`.

Looking at the function, we can see that with each iteration `first` gets closer by 2 to `last`, until they touch, at which point the function returns.

So, how many times does this happen? The answer is `(last - first) / 2`. If `first` always starts at 0, and `last` always starts at the last index of the array, then the number of executions will scale *linearly* with the length of the `array`. Let's call {the length of the array} `n`.

The function, thus, executes a constant number of operations `O(1)`, and is called O(`n`) times. `O(1) * O(n) == O(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume that you can shorten all of this to about 2-3 lines using expression operators. You can use the `?:` operator to determine the value of `result`, and then return the result.

`?:` is used as a sort of if/else statement, so that's why it makes it better. I'm not sure if I'm mixing up efficiency with readability, though.

Here's the example:

````
public int compute(int[] array, int first, int last) {
        int result = 0;
        
        result = first < last ? array[first] + compute(array, first+2, last) : first < array.length ? array[first] : result;
        
        return result;
    }```
````

Comment: What you post is technically correct, but I don't see how it answers the question about big-O notation? In fact your answer seems to be entirely unrelated to the question (other than concerning the same code).

Comment: Oh, whoops! I rushed the reading of this question, my bad. Thanks!